# Mysql [warning] 'user@localhost' has both a password and an authentication plugin specified

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql

I am using mysql-server-5.5.53 and ubuntu-14.04.1.

I have noticed below warning in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.

> Mysql [warning] : user' entry 'user@localhost' has both a password and an authentication plugin specified. The password will be ignored.

What causes this ? How do I get rid of this warning ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these warnings are spurious, and may be as a result of a bug being present in MySQL 5.5.x when either the `mysql_native_password` or `mysql_old_password` authentication plugins are specified in the `mysql.user` table.

> ...in MySQL 5.5, if the plugin column is set to either of those plugins and the password is specified, the server complains about it by logging warnings to the error log... Those warnings are spurious. They lead to the impression that something is wrong with the account when that is not the case.

Here's the bug report:

[Bug #71465: mysql.user row with plugin and password generates bogus warning](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71465)